# Is possible to profile C/C++ inline functions looking at the assembly?

Tags: c++, c, profiling, inline, disassembly

I want to measure the performance and in general the behaviour (how much assembly is created, etc) of some inline functions i use around my project. Other than profiling timings is it possible to look at the overral code expansion of the functions that use those inline ones?

I tried in Visual C++ and MingW (through NetBeans) to look at the Disassembly panel during debugging. With debug building every inline function use **call** in the assembly so they are not inlined. If i activate optimizations the assembly is so changed that i cannot even put breakpoints inside those functions.

Do you know any compiler settings (in GCC or VC, for example, just optimizing inline functions), book (i have "Efficient C++" that talks about inlining measuring timings) or anything else to understand better the topic?

Answer (score 1):

Tools like Intel VTune can profile inlined functions. They use the debugging info in the binary to map the instruction pointers back to the function "from which the code was derived" even when there is no actual `call` anymore in the assembly.

You can see this effect while looking at annotated assembly with some tools as well - the source code for several functions will be mixed together which reflects the inlining.

This process isn't perfect, since "to what function does this particular instruction belong" almost becomes a philosophical one rather than a technical one for some types of inlining (indeed, instructions may effectively be "shared" among several functions).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/47238hez.aspx) to the compiler switch in VS.  If you just want to test inline only enable this optimization.

Comment: I tried already but it tells me that is imcompatible with the /ZI option. What kind of debug information type is more preferable?

Comment: /ZI is for debug mode. You don't want to  check performance in debug mode anyway. You *have* to do that in release mode.

Comment: I understand but how can i see assembly information (that is debugging information) with a release build? I mean seeing for corrispondence between functions and their assembly code.